# Confusing Output of C Program

Tags: c, for-loop, output

Why compiler shows the value of `x` as `0` if I define `int x;` inside of `for` loop. But when removing `int x` from `for` loop gives the value of `x` as `10`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 0, i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        int x;
        x = 10;
    }
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: scope of your inner x would last until for loop, while scope of x=0 is till main function. Look it at from brace perspective.

Comment: 1. Get the compiler to issue as much warnings as possible.2. Who taught the loops start at 1 and require <= to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `int x` inside your for-loop, you create a new `x` variable. That means that you effectively have two `x` variables in your program, one which can be accessed from your `main()`-function and one which only can be accessed inside the for-loop. If you access `x` from within the for-loop, the compiler will choose the closest one.

If you were not to have `int x` inside your for-loop, there would only be one `x` and your program would output `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the scope of ***`int x`*** inside the for loop is limited to that for loop only.

> for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
>           {
>               int x;
>               x=10;
>       /*limited to this loop only, can't use outside of for loop*/
>           }

And int x outside of for loop but inside main() function would be available to all function inside main()

If you want to get value of `i` you may try this:

`x=i;`

instead of

`int x;
x=10;`

Answer (score 1):

As explained before, if you define a variable inside the `for` loop `int x; x = 10;` it will create a new variable that is only accessed inside the `for` loop.

So when you create variable `x` in `main` then create variable `x` in the `for` loop, you are currently referring the print `printf("%d", x);`  to the first `x` declared in `main` and that is why it is printing 0. This is because you initiated it to `0` in the line `int x = 0, i;` and it never changed. You never actually printed the `x` you initiated in the `for` loop.

But when you remove the `int x;` form the `for` loop, there is only one `x` initiated and you changed the value of `x` to `10` inside the loop. When you print `x` it gives you `10` which is the value that was assigned to it inside the `for` loop.

Hope this is not confusing.